# Can I use a wpdb object to connect to a non-Wordpress Oracle database

Tags: database, wpdb

I simply have a quick question. I've found information related to this, but I'm not completely sure if this is possible.
I know that I can create a second database connection using the wpdb object as follows:

```
$new_db = new wpdb(usr, pw, name, host);
```

However, is this compatible with an Oracle database that wouldn't have any of the Wordpress tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this got asked some time ago, it came time to actually implement this and ran into issues (see: [Connecting to external oracle database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341428/connecting-to-external-oracle-database/341433?noredirect=1))

The answer is no. Oracle is not a mysql based database, thus wordpress will not be able to connect to it via wpdb.

For more information see the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible. You can try

```
    function seconddb() {
         global $seconddb;
         $seconddb = new wpdb('Username','password','database name','localhost')
     }
     add_action('init','seconddb');
```

in your functions.php.
Then you can fire a query to the new db like 
`$seconddb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM yourtable..." );` instead of `$wpdb->get_row()`.